# Reading from a file and storing into an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a project that I am working on that is a maze solver, but I'm trying to figure out the read in from a file and storing it into an array. Most of the stuff that I have looked up to, they work with a created array by them in the program, while mine requires me to read from a file and construct it from there. So far, I have this:

```
       File map = new File("/Users/michelmaza/Downloads/Project1Map.txt"); //create an object of the file we are reading in
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(map); //create scanner to read file in
       LinkedList<String> mapping = new LinkedList<String>();//create array list to store the reading from the file

       while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            mapping.add(scanner.nextLine()); //Stores the file into the string where every 10 number is a new line
        }
        System.out.println(mapping); //test to see if it works.
        scanner.close(); //close the scanner since its not used anymore.
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { //catch in case the file is not found.
        System.out.println("There was no file found, please try again.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I output it, it throws me a whole array in a line, but I am trying to get in a map format basically a grid 10x10. Any tips or any advice on how I can approach this problem are welcome.

output as of right now
[2 3 3 0 0 0 1 0 0 3, 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 3, 3 3 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 3, 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0, 3 3 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3, 3 3 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3, 3 3 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3, 3 3 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3, 3 3 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3, 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3]

output wanted is

{2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3},
{3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3},
{3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 3},
{3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3},
{3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
{3, 3, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
{3, 3, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
{3, 3, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
{3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}

Comment: I think it's just that you are implicitly using the toString method of LinkedList, which would display each element on the same line. The answer is probably to iterate round the list (or use streams) and println each element (where each element is one of your sets of 10 numbers that was a line in the file)

Answer (score 0):

Hello I wrote a small example for your problem. Hope it will be useful for you.

In map.txt

```
2 3 3 0 0 0 1 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int mapSize = 10;
    List<List<String>> map = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("F:\\map.txt"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if(line != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mapSize; i++) {
                map.add(i, new ArrayList<>());
                String substring = line.trim().substring(0, mapSize * 2 - 1); // 2 for whitespaces
                line = line.trim().substring(mapSize * 2 - 1);
                map.get(i).addAll(Arrays.asList(substring.split(" ")));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    for(List<String> row : map) {
        System.out.println(String.join(",", row));
    }
}
```

Output :

```
2,3,3,0,0,0,1,0,0,3
3,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,3
3,3,0,0,0,0,3,3,0,3
3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
3,3,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3
3,3,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3
3,3,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3
3,3,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3
3,3,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3
3,3,3,2,3,3,3,3,3,3
```

Comment: I think I need to show what I am trying to do. So my .txt file is like this...

2 3 3 0 0 0 1 0 0 3
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 3
3 3 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 3
3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 3 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3
3 3 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3
3 3 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3
3 3 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3
3 3 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3
3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3

where 1 = starting point
2 = end point
3 = walls
0 = open paths

So when my code reads it, it shows it as a straight line, but I am trying to get it to be a grid of 10x10 and from what I have seen is that it makes every line as an array and that is what I am trying to do, hopefully that helps! Thanks

Comment: @MichelMazaL I rearranged my solution according to your case. Can you check again?

Answer (score 0):

Since your input file and expected output was not clear to me, I concentrate on reading the file, I am hoping each line already has 10 strings and has 10 lines to give you your grid

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> allLinesInFile = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/tmp/maze.input"));
        String[] asArray = allLinesInFile.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(asArray));
    }
}
```

---

Update :
Since now the inputs and outputs are clear, here is the full code :)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path mazeInputFile = Paths.get("/tmp/maze.input");
        Files.writeString(mazeInputFile, "2 3 3 0 0 0 1 0 0 3\n", StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
        Files.writeString(mazeInputFile, "3 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 3\n", StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        Files.writeString(mazeInputFile, "3 3 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 3\n", StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        Files.writeString(mazeInputFile, "3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n", StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        Files.writeString(mazeInputFile, "3 3 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3\n", StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        Files.writeString(mazeInputFile, "3 3 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3\n", StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        Files.writeString(mazeInputFile, "3 3 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3\n", StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        Files.writeString(mazeInputFile, "3 3 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3\n", StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        Files.writeString(mazeInputFile, "3 3 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3\n", StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        Files.writeString(mazeInputFile, "3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3\n", StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

        System.out.printf("Wrote mazeInputFile = %s\n", mazeInputFile);

        System.out.printf("Reading all Lines From Input file : %s\n", mazeInputFile);
        String[][] mazeInputArray = Files.lines(mazeInputFile) // Gives The lines in file as a Stream
                .filter(line -> line != null && !line.isBlank()) // Filter out unwanted Lines
                .map(line -> line.split(" ", 10)) // Split the line by Space with a maximum of 10 columns
                .toArray(String[][]::new); // Collect as a 2 dimensional Array
        System.out.println("-- --");


        System.out.println("-- Print the Array using a Java 8 Streams (my preference) --");
        String printableMaze = java.util.Arrays.stream(mazeInputArray).
                map(rows -> java.util.Arrays.stream(rows).
                        map(row -> String.join(",", row)). // join each row with a comma
                        collect(joining(",", "{", "}"))). // surround the row with a prefix { and suffix } and join the columns with a comma
                collect(joining(",\n")); // join each row with a leading comma and a newline
        System.out.printf("%s\n", printableMaze);
        System.out.println("-- --");
        System.out.println("-- Here, actually the reading of the file and printing can be combined to read huge files as well without taking too much memory --");
        System.out.println("-- --");

        System.out.println("-- Print the Array using good old for each loops, code looks kind of better but last comma remains --");
        for (String[] rows : mazeInputArray) {
            System.out.print("{");
            System.out.print(String.join(",", rows));
            System.out.print("},\n"); // needs ugly imperative code to get rid of the last comma :P
        }
        System.out.println("-- --");
    }
}
```

The Output looks like

```
Wrote mazeInputFile = /tmp/maze.input
Reading all Lines From Input file : /tmp/maze.input
-- --
-- Print the Array using a Java 8 Streams (my preference) --
{2,3,3,0,0,0,1,0,0,3},
{3,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,3},
{3,3,0,0,0,0,3,3,0,3},
{3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{3,3,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3},
{3,3,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3},
{3,3,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3},
{3,3,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3},
{3,3,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3},
{3,3,3,2,3,3,3,3,3,3}
-- --
-- Here, actually the reading of the file and printing can be combined to read huge files as well without taking too much memory --
-- --
-- Print the Array using good old for each loops, code looks kind of better but last comma remains --
{2,3,3,0,0,0,1,0,0,3},
{3,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,3},
{3,3,0,0,0,0,3,3,0,3},
{3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{3,3,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3},
{3,3,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3},
{3,3,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3},
{3,3,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3},
{3,3,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3},
{3,3,3,2,3,3,3,3,3,3},
-- --

Process finished with exit code 0
```

- I am not sure what you are looking to do but printing it is different from processing it.
- Why I kept it separate is because you can simply use the `mazeInputArray` for actually doing something with the input
- Printing is a PIA, using streams makes it easier to NOT think about edge cases as they are intelligently / implicitly handled.

Comment: Yes the file is already in format of 10 lines with 10 characters

Comment: Then Give this a try, this will read all lines from a file into a `List<String>` then you can split each line to get columns. No need to fiddle with Scanner and FIle, Java NIO is very nice especially when reading the whole file and it is not a huge file (like terabyte sized)

Comment: It pretty much outputs the same way that it was before, but you said I can split the lines, how do I do such thing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post / update the original question with a sample input file and expected sample output? then It's much easier to test :)
it need not be the whole file just 2 lines and corresponding output expected

Comment: I just updated it what I am getting and what I am looking to get, thanks!

Comment: Done, Updated my original answer, Please Accept if it is what you were looking for!